# Execute every Monday that is not the Monday following last Saturday in month

Tags: sql, datetime, t-sql, stored-procedure, scheduled-tasks

I think the following is good but wondering if it can be simplified or improved.

My condition for code execution is the following:

It is a Monday
AND
It is not the Monday following the last Saturday in the month.

This is the current `sql`:

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME = DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,'19000101',SYSDATETIME()),'19000101');


IF (
        (--is it a monday?
            SELECT DATEPART(dw,@now)
        ) = 2  

        AND

        (--is it not the monday following the last Saturday of the month?
            (
            SELECT DATEDIFF(
                            DAY,
                            @now-2, 
                            DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@now-2)+1,0)-1 
                        )
            ) > 6
        )
    )
BEGIN;

  ...
  ...

END;
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could [edit] your post to include the rest of the query/procedure... I'm sure our T-SQL reviewers would have plenty to say ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug the bit in between the `begin` and `end` is a couple of thousand lines and not really relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes, comments aren't the clearest way to make a script readable:

> ```
> IF (
>         (--is it a monday?
>             SELECT DATEPART(dw,@now)
>         ) = 2
> ```

Consider:

```
declare @MONDAY int;
set @MONDAY = 2;

if (datepart(weekday,@now) = @MONDAY)
```

Does one need a comment to figure out what's going on? I hope not!

This part however:

> ```
> DECLARE @now DATETIME = DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,'19000101',SYSDATETIME()),'19000101');
> ```

If it wasn't of the `@now` identifier, I'd wonder what this convoluted assignment intends to do.

Why not just do this instead?

```
declare @now date = cast(getdate() as date);
```

I mean, why work with a `datetime` when clearly you're only interested in the `date` part from that point on?

---

I find there's way too much whitespace in your code, you need to strike a balance between *wall-of-code* and *air code*.

Now, changing `@now` from a `datetime` to a `date` will break your code. The `@now-2` here:

> ```
> DATEDIFF(DAY, @now-2, DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@now-2)+1,0)-1
> ```

...is illegal because...

[image: one does not simply subtract an int from a date in t-sql]

I would extract that bit of logic into its own variable, for readability's sake, and using a `dateadd` function there would be no issue with subtracting 2 days from that date.

Comment: Adding the variable is a very nice idea and makes things much more readable. I prefer `DateTime`(as, for example, I can do `@now+1` in the code inside the `Begin-End`). The convoluted section was suggested to me by Itzik B-G, so I'm happy sticking with it - unfortunately I don't remember the rationale but he said we should use `SYSDATETIME()` rather than `getdate()`. My second condition I'm particularly interested to know whether it can be simplified or improved?

Comment: I will be sticking with DateTime for exactly the reason you have discovered - I like to be able to subtract or add integer's.

Comment: @whytheq except, with `dateadd` it's completely unambiguous what's being subtracted. Subtracting `2` from a `datetime` should be illegal as well... and [datetime is a legacy type](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15569958/1188513)

Comment: ....how did you find that reference to _my_ question on the same topic so quickly ?! ....spooky!!

Comment: Haha I hadn't noticed it was *your* question!

Comment: ....ok - that is very strange: maybe need to get my phd maths colleague to give us the odds of that. maybe we need to buy lottery tickets

Comment: (forgot to mention - the white-space is because lots of my life is spent in `MDX-studio` that has a very nice "format code" button ... I seem to end up formatting other languages the same)

Comment: is the version I've posted ok in respect of the ideas you have suggested? I think you have made it a lot more readable. The logic of how it works is unchanged - I'm still curious to know if there is a more elegant way of checking for the last Saturday of a specified month.

Comment: _One does not simply not upvote this answer_

Answer (score 0):

Following Mat's Mug's advice I have the following

```
DECLARE @now DATE = DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,'19000101',SYSDATETIME()),'19000101');


DECLARE @MONDAY INT = 2;
DECLARE @dayBeforeYESTERDAY DATE = DATEADD(dd,-2,@now);
DECLARE @LastDayOfMthfor_dayBeforeYESTERDAY DATE = DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@dayBeforeYESTERDAY)+1,0));

IF (

        (SELECT DATEPART(dw,@now)) = @MONDAY        
        AND
        (
            --check to see if it is not following the last Saturday in month
            (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,@dayBeforeYESTERDAY, @LastDayOfMthfor_dayBeforeYESTERDAY))
            > 6
        )
    )
BEGIN;
...
...
END;
```

Comment: If you want additional feedback for a revised version, it would be better to ask a new "follow-up" question (linking back to this one) - self-answers are allowed and even encouraged, but they should be in the form of a peer review... this answer isn't really an answer/review, I'd recommend you either edit it into a "review-shaped answer", or remove it. Cheers!